# How to use Primefaces in OSGi-Framework karaf?

Tags: java, primefaces, osgi, apache-karaf, pax-web

I want to use [Primefaces](https://www.primefaces.org/#primefaces) in [karaf](https://karaf.apache.org/). For that i combined the [karaf-war-example](https://github.com/apache/karaf/tree/master/examples/karaf-war-example) with [pax-web-primefaces-example](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/samples/war-jsf-primefaces) and get a working karaf-feature which can be found at [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/matthiaw/primefaces-karaf-test/src/master/).

The example works fine, but when i want to extend the project with any other primeface-example, like [clock](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/clock.xhtml), [ThemeSwitcher](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/themeSwitcher.xhtml) or a [Panel](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/accordionPanel.xhtml), it not works correct.

So far i found out that i need to add javax.annotations as dependency. This compile correct, but shows not the expected results in browser. Maybe the missing views are broken because the javax.annotations is not added to the lib-folder in war. But i added it manually to the war and get no progress.

Rendering is

[image: Primefaces wrong rendered]

but should look like

[image: Primefaces right rendered]

I am not so skilled in osgi and felix that i not understood what is needed. Also i have the problem that no exception occurs, so i have no hint where i should look at.

Comment: Does a plain jsf component work in this project? How does a 'view source' look like?

Comment: Yes. Plain JSF works.

Comment: Source of working karaf in browser is saved at https://bitbucket.org/matthiaw/primefaces-karaf-test/src/master/RenderResult.txt

Comment: At the moment there is no out-of-the-box solution available. The best analysis with the problem can be found at https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXWEB-1244 and https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/ops4j/_KBO-YDACgA/Nh78LxbGAwAJ